# Why was/is NULL used in C++?

Tags: c++

The C++ standard defines the null pointer to be `0`. In a lot of code I've seen the `NULL` macro used however.

Why is it so? If the standard defines `NULL` to be `0` anyway, why use a special constant for it?

Is it just an aesthetic choice, or is there a more practical reason for it? Or was there a reason in the past that is no longer valid, i.e. holdovers from older drafts of the C++ standard?

How and why did `NULL` begin to be used instead of `0`?

Comment: I would say it is just an influence of C programmers, where NULL was used as a standard value for initializing pointers.

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/5604/

Comment: @cnluzon Aha, so it's a holdover. I always wondered, and never found a good explanation. Well, you can post that as an answer.

Comment: @jsantander Why did you post that link? I'm not asking which I should use, which is the question from that link.

Comment: I had the impression that it provided an explanation of the meaning and the history of it... might had read it too fast.

Comment: In the old C days, NULL wasn't always zero - sometimes it was a pointer to a random location.  If you're mixing old C code and new C++ code, on an old system, it is best to check for NULL instead of zero.

Comment: The current C++ standard (C++11) prescribes [nullptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/nullptr) instead.

Comment: Bjarne Stroustrup has stated that there is never a need to use NULL in a correctly written C++ program. @cup Please provide an example of that unsupported assertion. I've been using C since 1982 and I've never encountered it.

Comment: @EJP You've got one year up on me: I've been using it since 1983.  I've used two C compilers where it wasn't 0, both in the early 80s.  One was the Data General MV8000 eclipse.  The other was HP3000.  I remember these distinctly because we ported code from SunOS and parts where they tested for if(xptr) ... when xptr was NULL it still executed.  Then we found that NULL wasn't 0 on those machines.  Nowadays, NULL is always zero.

Comment: @jsantander OK, I read it again, and it gets more interesting after the first 2-3 posts. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a leftover from C, where `NULL` is often defined as `(void*)0`. In C, because of conversion rules, it makes `NULL` implicitly convertible to any other pointer type while remaining non convertible to integer types:

```
int* a = NULL; /* OK */
int b = NULL;  /* ERROR */
```

C++ however does not have such loose type conversions, and therefore `NULL` is defined as `0` in C++. While this means that `int b = NULL;` is legal, compilers are generally smart enough to emit a warning if you do so as they recognized that `NULL` is a special macro thus preserving some of the type safety... when the warning works.

Of course, in C++11, one should use `nullptr` instead. In C++03 though even [Stroustrup](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#null) already recommended using `0` rather than a macro.

Answer (score 2):

`NULL` is more descriptive than `0`, and they have different fundamental meanings. `0` is an integer number, while `NULL` indicates something like "no value" or "points to nothing". Similarly `PI` is more descriptive in your code than `3.1415926535897`.

This was a compromise until C++11 where you should be using the `nullptr` keyword. Now, in addition to the added clarity, you get actual compiler support for your intention. For example `int x = NULL;` doesn't really make much sense because even though `NULL` boils down to an integer, its *meaning* is not that of an integer. `int x = nullptr;` will properly error.

Comment: There's a difference, though - `3.1415926535897` is harder to remember, and longer to type than `PI`, while the `0` is actually shorter to type than `NULL`. Also `if (ptr)` is shorter to type than `if (ptr != NULL)`. I admit I prefer `0` because it's shorter to type overall.

Comment: Even if `PI` happened to be exactly `3`, we would still use the macro (or constexpr or whatever). **You should care about clarity and semantics more than number of characters**. Both `NULL` and `nullptr` are convertible to `bool` which is why they both work fine in the `if()` statement without `!=`.

Comment: @tenfour: I would urge people to use a typed constant indeed ;)

Answer (score 1):

A pointer is not an integer - their types are different. So `int* p = 0;` somehow looks wrong, especially given the case the `int* p = 5;` is a compiler error.

People are using `NULL` ([reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/NULL)) to have a special word for a null pointer constant, i.e. indicating a pointer which points to nothing. But `NULL` is just a workaround and often realized as a macro which in C++ (often) resolves to the integer `0`.

C++11 has introduced `nullptr` ([reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/nullptr)) to solve this problem once and for all.

Comment: If that is so (the type difference), then why does the compiler allow it? `int* p = 0;` I mean.

Comment: Because `0` is a null pointer constant: "A null pointer constant is an integral constant expression (5.19) rvalue of integer type that evaluates to zero. (C++03,4.10/1)"

Answer (score 1):

I would say it is just an influence of C programmers, where NULL was used as a standard value for initializing pointers.

Comment: I don't understand why anyone would downvote the *most likely reason*.

Comment: maybe it's because I did not reference any standard. However, I do believe this is the reason. It's easy to take old customs to new languages, specially from C to C++, because although they are different, you actually _can_ mix. One could even argue, as it has been said before, that NULL is more informative. For someone who has been programming for a long time in C, it might. Maybe you don't _need_ NULL as a new C++ programmer, but you are used to it and it _soaks_ your C++ code.