# Can the expression "(ptr == 0) != (ptr == (void*)0)" really be true?

Tags: c++, pointers

I read this claim in [a forum thread](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/5604/#msg24758) linked to [in a comment by @jsantander](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22932360/why-was-is-null-used-in-c#comment35006414_22932360):

> Keep in mind that when you assign or compare a pointer to zero, there is some special magic that occurs behind the scenes to use the correct pattern for the given pointer (which may not actually be zero). This is one of the reasons why things like `#define NULL (void*)0` are evil  – if you compare a `char*` to `NULL` that magic has been explicitly (and probably unknowingly) turned off, and an invalid result may happen. Just to be extra clear:
>
> ```
> (my_char_ptr == 0) != (my_char_ptr == (void*)0)
> ```

So the way I understand it, for an architecture where the NULL pointer is, say, `0xffff`, the code `if (ptr)`, would compare ptr to `0xffff` instead of to 0.

Is this really true? Is it described by the C++ standard?

If true, it would mean that 0 can be safely used even for architectures that have a non-zero NULL pointer value.

**Edit**

As an extra clarification, consider this code:

```
char *ptr;
memset(&ptr, 0, sizeof(ptr));
if ((ptr == (void*)0) && (ptr != 0)) {
    printf("It can happen.\n");
}
```

This is how I understand the claim of this forum post.

Comment: yes, the pattern can be different, and 0 denotes the nullpointer, thus comparing against this pattern (meaning also that the expression can never be true). To make things easier, use `nullptr` though.

Comment: Actually I have never seen any implementation where NULL was different from 0.

Comment: @MichaelWalz: I've never seen a blue whale ;-)

Comment: @MichaelWalz FWIW, I've heard of a few (at least in C).  IIRC, K&R I listed a couple.  (The one I remember was a machine from Honeywell Bull, but I'm pretty sure that there were others.)

Comment: Re the edit: it still doesn't change anything.  Whether `ptr` is a null pointer after the `memset` is not specified, but `ptr == (void*)0` will evaluate to true if and only if `ptr` is a null pointer, and `ptr != 0` will evaluate true if and only if `ptr` is not a null pointer.

Comment: Actually `"It can happen"` *can* happen per the standard, but not exactly for the reason you're talking about in this question. If the representation of a null pointer is *not* all-bits-zero on the implementation, then the `memset` can write a trap value (or generally: an invalid value) to `ptr` and you have undefined behavior as soon as you look at it to evaluate `ptr == anything`. Undefined behavior includes taking an "impossible" branch.

Comment: http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html "the definition of NULL is 0". One of the improvements from C that C++ fixed, was to de-mystify NULL. In C, NULL is something more fuzzy and vague, and could theoretically be something else than 0.

Comment: I thought the reason that `(void *)NULL` is evil is that you would then no longer be able to assign NULL to any pointer without a cast since a `void *` is not implicitly convertible to any other pointer type.

Comment: @MichaelWalz Win32s did that, because 0 is where MS-DOS has its interrupt vector: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/03/28/10405881.aspx

Comment: @Joker_vD lol, didn't know that Win32 offsets values by 4194304. But one part I don't understand is, they don't need to do this with Virtual Memory enabled, which it is from Win95. So it would have been needed only for Win3.1 and below.

Comment: @sashoalm: Win32*s* was Win3.1 only. s stands for subset.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

There's two parts to your question. I'll start with:

> If true, it would mean that 0 can be safely used even for architectures that have a non-zero NULL pointer value.

You are mixing up "value" and "representation". The *value* of a null pointer is called the *null pointer value*.  The *representation* is the bits in memory that are used to store this value. The representation of a null pointer could be anything, there is no requirement that it is all-bits-zero.

In the code:

```
char *p = 0;
```

`p` is guaranteed to be a null pointer. It might not have all-bits-zero.

This is no more "magic" than the code:

```
float f = 5;
```

`f` does not have the same representation (bit-pattern in memory) as the int `5` does, yet there is no problem.

The C++ standard defines this. The text changed somewhat in C++11 with the addition of `nullptr`; however in all versions of C and C++, the integer literal `0` when converted to a pointer type generates a null pointer.

From C++11:

> A *null pointer constant* is an integral constant expression prvalue of integer type that evaluates to zero or a prvalue of type std::nullptr_t. A null pointer constant can be converted to a pointer type; the result is the *null pointer value* of that type and is distinguishable from every other value of object pointer or function pointer type. Such a conversion is called a *null pointer conversion*.

`0` is a *null pointer constant*, and `(char *)0` for example is a *null pointer value* of type `char *`.

It's immaterial whether a null pointer has all-bits-zero or not. What matters is that a null pointer is guaranteed to be generated when you convert an integral constexpr of value `0` to a pointer type.

Moving onto the other part of your question.  **The text you quoted is complete garbage** through and through. There's no "magic" in the idea that a conversion between types results in a different representation, as I discuss above.

The code `my_char_ptr == NULL` is guaranteed to test whether or not `my_char_ptr` is a null pointer.

It would be evil if you write in your own source code, `#define NULL (void*)0`. This is because it is undefined behaviour to define any macro that might be defined by a standard header.

However, the standard headers can write whatever they like so as the Standard requirements for null pointers are fulfilled. Compilers can "do magic" in the standard header code; for example there doesn't have to be a file called `iostream` on the filesystem; the compiler can see `#include <iostream>` and then have hardcoded all of the information that the Standard requires `iostream` to publish.  But for obvious practical reasons, compilers generally don't do this; they allow the possibility for independent teams to develop the standard library.

Anyway, if a C++ compiler includes `#define NULL (void *)0` in its own header, and as a result something non-conforming happens, then the compiler would be non-conforming obviously. And if nothing non-conforming happens then there is no problem.

I don't know who the text you quote would direct its "is evil" comment at. If it is directed at compiler vendors telling them not to be "evil" and put out non-conforming compilers, I guess we can't argue with that.

Comment: "generates a compilation error because in C++ there is no implicit conversion from `void *` to another pointer type." Such a conversion is not necessary. There is a conversion from any pointer type (ignoring `const` for a while) to `void*`, so `my_char_ptr` gets converted to a `void*` and the whole right comparison is performed on `void*`.

Comment: Have fixed that, thanks. I thought it converted `void *` to the other type, but in fact it converts the other type to `void *`

Comment: `offsetof` is something that "magic" is a good description for. You can't implement it yourself without invoking UB, but the compiler can because compilers can define their own behaviour, you might say :)

Comment: Hats off for the `float f = 5;` example.  The conversion of the null pointer constant is a bit special (since it is only triggered by constant expressions, and only for one special value), but it's still a lot more like what happens in the `int` to `float` conversion than anything else.

Comment: Your answer is really good, I'll mark it accepted (even though I had accepted @Steve's previously, yours is a lot more detailed).

Comment: @Matt From [Damon's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22938645/492336), it's theoretically possible to have a different null value representation for each pointer type. The C++ standard allows it.

Comment: @sashoalm: As a possibly-silly example, you could write a C++ implementation where a pointer contains two fields: one for the address and one with some type information. Then of course a null pointer isn't all-bits-zero, and is different for every type (except cases where the standard says certain pointer types have the same representation, such as `T*` and `T const*`). In C++ you never need that information stored in a pointer, but it might help debugging or a garbage collector or something :-)

Comment: @sashoalm Yes; it also guarantees that they all compare equal

Answer (score 12):

I think the forum post you link to is incorrect (or we have misinterpreted what it means by `!=`). The two sub-expressions have different semantics but the same result. Assuming that `my_char_ptr` really has type `char*` or similar, and a valid value:

`my_char_ptr == 0` converts `0` to the type of `my_char_ptr`. That yields a null pointer because `0` is an example of a so-called "null pointer constant", which is defined in the standard. It then compares the two. The comparison is true if and only if `my_char_ptr` is a null pointer, because only null pointers compare equal to other null pointers.

`my_char_ptr == (void*)0` converts `my_char_ptr` to `void*`, and then compares that to the result of converting `0` to `void*` (which is a null pointer). The comparison is true if and only if `my_char_ptr` is a null pointer because when you convert a pointer to `void*` the result is a null pointer if and only if the source is a null pointer.

The issue of whether null pointers are represented with 0 bits or not is interesting but irrelevant to the analysis of the code.

The practical danger of thinking that `NULL` is a null pointer (rather than merely a null pointer constant) is that you might think that `printf("%p", NULL)` has defined behaviour, or that `foo(NULL)` will call the `void*` overload of `foo` rather than the `int` overload, and so on.

Comment: Re the final paragraph, at least one compiler defines `NULL` as something like `__nullptr`, a compiler built-in which parses like `0`, but causes a warning if it isn't converted into a pointer type.  (Or at least it did; this feature may have been removed with the introduction of `nullptr`.)

Comment: @JamesKanze: Useful. So as with all non-required diagnostics, the only practical danger of using that compiler is that it lulls you into a false sense of security and you expect your mistakes to be caught for you by other compilers ;-)

Comment: Or rather, it gets you used to writing code without that mistake.  (Looking back, all of the places I've worked have required the use of `NULL` when we wanted a null pointer.  Always recognizing that it is information for the reader, not the compiler.)

Comment: And by the way, didn't you mean `printf("%p", NULL)`.  If someone thinks that `NULL` has a pointer type, then they would assume that `printf("%x", NULL)` is undefined behavior.

Comment: Ironically, `printf("%p", NULL)` is correct only with the "evil" definition!

Comment: I moved the accepted answer to @Matt, because his was very detailed (but came late). I hope it's not a problem?

Comment: @sashoalm: course not, you're allowed to change your mind when a better one comes along.

Answer (score 8):

**No**, because they incidentially used the only case where it is guaranteed to work as example.
**Otherwise, yes.**

Although practially you probably won't ever see a difference, strictly speaking, the concern is correct.

The C++ standard requires (4.10) that:

1. A null pointer constant (which is either an integral constant expression that evaluates to `0`, or a prvalue of type `std::nullptr_t`) converts to the null pointer of any type.
2. Two null pointers *of the same type* compare equal.
3. A prvalue of type pointer-to-cv-T can be converted to pointer-to-cv-void, and the null pointer value will be adjusted accordingly.
4. Pointers of derived classes can be converted to pointers of base classes, and the null pointer value will be adjusted accordingly.

This means, if you are pedantic about the wording, that the null pointers of `void` and `char` and `foo_bar` are not only *not necessarily zero bit patterns*, but **also** are *not necessarily the same*. Only null pointers of the same type are necessarily the same (and actually, not even that is true, it only says that they must *compare equal*, which isn't the same thing).

The fact that it explicitly says *"The null pointer value is converted to the null pointer value of the
destination type"* signifies that this is not only an absurd, theoretical contortion of the wording, but indeed intended as a legitimate feature of an implementation.

That is regardless of the fact that the same literal `0` will convert to the null pointer of each type.

Incidentially, in their example, they compared to `void*`, which will work due to the above conversion rule. Also, in practice, the null pointer for every type is a zero bit pattern on every architecture that you are likely to encounter in your life (though of course, that's not guaranteed).

Comment: "The fact ... signifies". I don't think it does signify that, because two values of different types necessarily are different values, even with the same representation. Of `uint32_t` to `int32_t` conversion you might say, "the value zero is converted to the value zero of the destination type" even though in that case they are guaranteed to have the same representation. What you say is true, though, pointer-to-object types in general aren't required in the C++ standard to all have the same size, let alone representation.

Comment: ... I think there's something linking `char*` and `void*` but I forget the details.

Answer (score 7):

First, I'm not sure that `(charPtr == 0) != (charPtr == (void*)0)` is allowed, even in C++.  In both cases, you're
converting a null pointer constant (`0`) to a pointer, which
results in a null pointer.  And all null pointers should compare
equal.

Second, while I don't know the context of the passage you cite,
you really don't have to worry about `NULL` being `(void*)0`:
user code cannot legally define `NULL` (at least not if it
includes any standard headers), and the C++ standard requires
`NULL` to be defined as a null pointer constant; i.e. an
constant integral expression evaluating to 0.  (Note that
despite its name, a null pointer constant cannot have a pointer
type.)  So it might be `0` (the more or less standard
definition, since the very beginnings of C), or possibly `0L`,
or even `(1-1)`, but not `((void*)0)`.  (Of course, it might
also be something like `__nullptr`, a compiler built-in constant
which evaluates to integer `0`, but triggers a warning if not
converted immediately into a null pointer.

Finally: there's no requirement that a null pointer have all
0 bits, and there certainly have been cases where this wasn't
the case.  On the other hand, there is a requirement that
comparing a null pointer to a null pointer constant will
evaluate to true; it's up to the compiler to make it work.  And
since `NULL` is required to be defined as a null pointer
constant, whether you use `NULL` or `0` is purely a question of
personal preference and convention.

EDIT:

Just to clarify a little: the critical point involves conversion
of a "null pointer constant", an integral constant expression
evaluating to 0.  What can surprise people is:

```
int zero = 0;       //  NOT a constant expression.
void* p1 = reinterpret_cast<void*>( zero );
void* p2 = 0;
if ( p1 == p2 )     //  NOT guaranteed!
```

The results of converting a non-constant expression which
evaluates to zero to a pointer is *not* guaranteed to be a null
pointer.

Comment: OK, the `char*` part is really a problem, but I was quoting the forum post verbatim. But pretend it's `void *ptr`. The real point I think is that `ptr == 0` could give true even if the memory occupied by the pointer is not all 0-bits.

Comment: @sashoalm: exactly. `ptr == 0` doesn't mean "is my pointer all bits zero?". It means "is my pointer null?"

Comment: @SteveJessop Yes, and the forum post also implies that explicit conversion `(void*)0` would yield an all-0-bits pointer even for architectures where the null pointer is not all-0-bits (and thus also a non-null pointer). Hence the claim that `(void*)0 != 0`.

Comment: @sashoalm But of course.  The real point is that `if ( ptr == 0 )` _must_ be true if `ptr` is a null pointer (and false otherwise), regardless of how the system represents null pointers.

Comment: @sashoalm Except that `(void*)0` is _required_ to evaluate to a null pointer, by the standard.